# Possible to use jQuery on ajax output elements?

Tags: jquery

So i have this output generated from a jQuery function i built (ajax) which is a list of registered users to a ceratain event. Behind every name there should be a delete button, where I can delete users from the event, using ajax and jQuery.

The problem im running into is that the jQuery function to delete them doesnt work, so my question is "is it possible to use jQuery on ajax outputs?" ?

The jQuery i wrote works perfect for static elements but not for the ajax-output things.

All the best,
Marten

Comment: You will need to show us the jQuery code that you are using.

Comment: Do you have some code to post? Without code, it's difficult to tell exactly what the problem is, but you could try looking at `.live()`: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) jQuery function. It allows binding of events to elements not yet in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Look at jQuery's function [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass dataType: html to ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "sample_ajax_page.htm",
  dataType: "html"
});
```